# How can I create a folder by a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a folder on my C:\ or something along those lines.

I've just started looking into making chrome extensions but what I think i'm asking for should be doable. I've looked on other SO posts but they don't seem to work anymore (not sure if its due to upgrading chrome version etc).

My code is as follows:

**MANIFEST.JSON**

```
{  
   "manifest_version":2,
   "name":"Folder Creator",
   "description":"Folder Creator",
   "version":"1.0",
   "browser_action":{  
      "default_icon":"icon.png",
      "default_title": "Create",
      "default_popup":"popup.html"
   },
   "permissions":[  
      "activeTab",
      "downloads",
      "downloads.open",
      "tabs"
   ]
}
```

**POPUP.HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sam rules</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <p>ID Number:</p>
            <input type="text" name="IDNumber">
            <p>Customer</p>
            <input type="text" name="Customer">
            </br>
            </br>
            <button onclick="create()">Create Folder</button>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**POPUP.JS**

```
 function create() {
     var myObject, newfolder;
     myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
     newfolder = myObject.CreateFolder("c:\\newtmp\\");
 }
```

Comment: ActiveX is IE only. Chrome extensions do not have filesystem access.

Comment: Thanks @DanielHerr Can you suggest how I can do this then or does it not work?

Comment: Nope, you'll have to write an additional external utility that will accept [messages from your extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).